# accept:pdf being passed as a prop to div instead of input

Tags: html, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I'm using semantic-ui-react, and trying to validate some input in a form by passing the accept:pdf prop as shown here:

```
<Input label='Business Plan__'
  fluid
  accept= ".pdf"
  type="file"
  style={{ padding: '.5em 0em' }} vertical
  value={this.state.projectFile}
  onChange={event => this.setState({ projectFile: event.target.value })}
/>
```

however, instead of getting a pleasant little pdf validation in the actual input component, I'm getting this guy:

```
<div accept=".pdf" class="ui fluid labeled input" style="padding: 0.5em 0em;">
  <div class="ui label label">Business Plan__</div>
  <input type="file" value="">
</div>
```

As you can see, the div is getting the accept prop instead of the input element. It's super weird because on the semantic-ui-react sandbox I can literally copy and paste the first code block (well, with the exception of the last two lines) and it works as I would expect it to.

Answer (score 1):

That actually appears to be a bug with `semantic-ui-react`. You should open a bug reporting that the input attribute of `accept` is not getting passed through to the `<input/>`.

One workaround would be to pass children on your `Input` component. This actually requires you to pass an `<input/>` tag, where you can define the `accept` attribute.

```
<Input
  fluid
  style={{ padding: '.5em 0em' }} 
  vertical
  value={this.state.projectFile}
  onChange={event => this.setState({ projectFile: event.target.value })}
>
  <input type="file" accept= ".pdf" />
  <Icon name='folder' /> {/* You don't need this line, but you can do this. */}
</Input>
```